# Bootstrap 3 grid column center

Tags: css, grid, center

how can i make this list with grid system by Bootstrap 3. 
[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX5z7.png)

Just to center the columns inside row..I have code like

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">Predchozi</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">4</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">5</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">6</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">7</div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-center">Dalsi</div>
            </div>
```

where `col-center` is set just `margin: 0 auto;`

Even if i am using `center-block`by bootstrap, i am not possible co center all these divs still...

Thanks for every advice!